# How do I release unused space in docker volume to the system?

Tags: docker

My server is at 0% free space.  I just deleted 100gb of data in one of my docker volumes in an actively running container.

How do I free up the space and release it to the host system so that I am not at 0%. Do I need to stop the docker container to release it?

Thanks!

Comment: Docker has several storage backends that work differently from each other, but in general there's no such thing as unused space within them; storage is only allocated away from the host filesystem when it's _actually used_. It's not like a virtual machine that preallocates space to be used to emulate a hard drive -- instead, each container (typically, depending on selected backend) just has different filesystem namespaces giving them views into a subset of the files that _actually exist on the host_.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you deleted content and aren't seeing space freed up, there are several possible reasons for that. One is that that content already existed in a parent to that container; you need to delete _all_ references to an inode to let its blocks be freed, including references from snapshots, parent COW images, etc. For the same reason, a file that's still open won't be free'd on deletion with `rm`, because still-open file handles count as references.

Comment: All that said, this kind of fact-intensive investigation (how the system is configured, where/when/how the files you deleted were created at, which references to them still exist, etc) is one I would wear my sysadmin hat for, not my software developer hat. As such, I'd argue that it would me more topical at [unix.se] than here.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, that was very helpful and helped me understanding of how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the container is still running, and deleting files doesn't show any drop in disk usage, odds are good that the process inside your container has those file handles open. The OS won't release the underlying file and reclaim the space until all processes with open file handles close those file handles, or the process exits. In short, you likely need to restart the container.

Comment: Could also be that the files were created in a parent build step and thus are included in a snapshot that we're forked from.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if they are deleting the files from the volume, that would be a copy of what's in the image, and you'd see space free up. The volume, by default, isn't using overlay like the image layers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that assumes this is really a volume, and not being deleted from the container filesystem. We'd need a lot more debugging from the OP to know for sure.

Comment: Indeed; I did miss the "volume" word in the question. If that's the case, there should be nothing unique/special to Docker here at all, and just the usual potential problems that cause space assigned to deleted files not to be freed (which can include snapshots, but not Docker-created ones).

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is clean your docker system by using:

`docker system prune` : https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

This will remove unused containers, clean images and more.

Comment: Does it reclaim space I freed up in the current used volume?  
I don't have any unused containers/images etc..

Comment: you will have dangling images for sure.

Comment: You may need to give more space to your docker machine, but most people have dangling images and containers in their docker systems so this should help clean it up for you